# Show form by button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to make a *management application* with a Windows Forms form and I want to *display* one *login form* and when the *login button* is clicked, the second form should appear.

I tried this:

```
MainProgramm.BringToFrot();
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to create a new instance of the second form (`new SecondForm()`).

Comment: Is *"BringToFrot"* actually in your code or did you mistype it for this question? The method name is *[BringToFront](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront?view=netframework-4.8)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a FormMain and you want to call a different form from it, you should create an instance of the second form and show it on the screen (as per @Tvde1 comment):

```cs
SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm();
secondForm.Show();
```

If you want the new form to act as a dialog box, you can use:

```cs
secondForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your example code. Maybe you should try:

```cs
MainProgramm.BringToFront(); // add the missing 'n' letter
```

then add a new line like this:

```cs
MainProgramm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you pretty much to do is add the following code in the ***Click action of the button*** that you want:

```
MainProgram mainProgram=new MainProgram();
mainProgram.ShowDialog();
```

Or if you prefer

```
MainProgram mainProgram=new MainProgram();
mainProgram.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Show()*** method to display form.

```
MainProgram mainProgram = new MainProgram();
mainProgram.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the `OnLoad()` method of the main form, and transfer control to the login form modally with the `.ShowDialog()` method.

For example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        var dlg = new LoginForm();
        dlg.UserID = Environment.UserName;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        var id = dlg.UserID;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = $"Login: {id}";

    }
}
```